# vba save excel and copy document to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

Sometimes I need to reply an e-mail with a calculation I made in Excel. To do this, I first save the Excel-file, search for the file in Explorer, Copy it and finally paste it in the body of the mail (reply) to add it as attachement of my reply.

I know that you can Save to a particular folder using VBA. I'm wondering now whether it is also possible to copy the file to the Clipboard using VBA. This way, I can paste it directly in the mail.

Comment: In Excel 2013, you can go File->Share->Email->Send as Attachment while directly viewing the file.

Comment: When I save a file in Excel and then go into Outlook to compose an email, I click the attachment button (the paperclip in the toolbar), and Excel offers that file I just saved at the top of the list of proposed attachments. That doesn't work for you?

Comment: I've never thought about the paperclip, but indeed : it's a nice shortcut! Thx!!!

Comment: Your question has almost become obsolete. So let's consider this: You're exhausted and you can spare only one button click which will for 1 save the Excel file, open Outlook, attach the file to a new email (maybe close Excel) before your strength reappears to write the email or for 2, Outlook is already running with the ready email and the button click will save the Excel file, attach it to the email and even send it. These two scenarios would trump the proposed solutions so far. So that's where your question (and the answer) should be going to. BTW both are possible using VBA.

Comment: You are right. I'm indeed looking for what you suggest : "Outlook is already running with the ready email and the button click will save the Excel file, attach it to the email and even send it. " I suppose that by "ready email" you refer to the mail I want to reply on? So if someone could help me with this. I know the vba code for saving a file and attaching a file to a new created mail, but not how to attach that saved file to an existing mail (the mail I want to reply to).

Comment: OK, now you got a start. Now paste the code into the question, change the question to a real one titled something like 'Automating Excel File Attachment Using VBA', describe EXACTLY what you want to do and you might get some cool answers. You might even consider asking a new question. I hate email, so i don't know enough about Outlook therefore I can't help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testmail()
Dim oOutlook As Object
Dim Reply As Object
Dim Original As Object

Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Original = oOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set Reply = Original.Reply
With Reply
.Attachments.Add 'refer to attachment
.Display

End With
```

This code will do the job. I will still have to add some code to save the Excel-file, but once the file is saved, the code above will add the saved document to a reply to the mail selected in Outlook.